# Leibniz's alternating series test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

the definition of this test is:

> if $a_n$ decreases monotonically and goes to 0 in the limit then the alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^na_n$ converges

my question is: why does the series $a_n$ has to be monotonically descending,
isn't it enough for $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$ ?
can someone give me an example for that?

Comment: Also see earlier thread [Monotonicity in alternating Series](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354192/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Counter example:

Check the following alternating series diverges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^na_n\;\;,\;\;a_n=\begin{cases}0&,\;\;n\;\;\text{is odd}\\{}\\\frac1n&,\;\;n\;\;\text{is even}\end{cases}$$

Comment: thanks! a great example that can be easily understood!

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt {n+(-1)^n}}$$
then by taylor series we have
$$(-1)^na_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}\left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{2\sqrt n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$$
The first and the last term give a convergent series by Leibniz theorem and by comparison with the Riemann series respectively and the term $\frac{1}{2n}$ gives a divergent series hence the series $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $a_n = 1/n$ when $n$ is even, and $a_n=1/n^2$ when $n$ is odd.  Then $a_n \to 0$ but $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ diverges.

Comment: why does it diverge?

Comment: Perhaps you can prove that yourself!