# Monotonicity in Alternating Series Test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Alternating series test states that if {$x_n$} is a decreasing sequence converging to $0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}x_n$ converges. Monotonicity is important because otherwise examples such the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/354195/386362) can be constructed, where $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}x_n = 0$ but the series diverges. I wanted to know how to construct these examples. Does this have to do with rearrangement? In the link the person gives an example, but I am not sure what thinking to have when constructing these examples.

Comment: You want the sum of positive elements to diverge to infinity faster then the sum of negative elements or to have that sum of negative elements doesn't converge.

Answer (score 0):

No, it really has nothing to do with rearrangement.  In the example you cite, the series of odd-numbered terms is divergent and the series of even-numbered terms is convergent, so the sum will clearly diverge.

Obviously, you can construct as many examples as you like by using this pattern.