# Show that the monotonicity in the alternating series test is necessary.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

We need to show that monotonicity in the alternating series test is necessary.  I know that it is otherwise, examples like the following:

[Monotonicity in alternating Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354192/monotonicity-in-alternating-series/354195#354195)

could be constructed. But how can we rigorously prove this?

Comment: It’s not necessary, though it is sufficient. For example you can break monotonocoty by adjusting the first 20 terms

Comment: They mean that monotonicity cannot be dropped from the theorem. Not that convergence of an alternating series implies monotnicity.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy i think you are right, but it certainly sounds very odd to me; of course its certainly not true that monotonicity is necessary and sufficient for the alternating series to converge...

Answer (score 0):

To prove monotonicity is necessary, you simply need a counterexample, i.e. a divergent alternating series which has $|a_n|\to 0$, but not monotonically. Try:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2-1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2+1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 3-1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3+1}\ldots$$

Comment: How come we can just show a counter-example? When we prove something don't we need to rigorously prove it?

Comment: You need to understand that your task is to **disprove** the claim: "Every series where the terms alternate signs and converge to 0 converges."

To disprove a claim of the form "Every something X has property Y" it is enough to provide one instance of X that does not have property Y. If the demonstration that the given instance of X does indeed not have property Y is given to satisfactory levels, that's all there is to do.

Comment: @user1234 You know that having the properties of $|a_n|\to 0$ and monotonicity guarantees a given series is convergent. Your question is asking whether monotonicity is necessary, that is, is just $|a_n|\to 0$ sufficient to determine that the series is convergent, or do we need monotonicity to guarantee it? The example I give in my answer proves that $|a_n|\to 0$ without monotonicity is not sufficient to guarantee convergence.